# Apache Airflow provider Sqlite Module not found/error for hook "airflow.hooks.dbapi import DbApiHook"

Tags: sqlite, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am quite new to Airflow and started practicing with it but currently stuck with a broken DAG that complains about 'airflow.hooks.dbapi' module not found.

Below is the code snippet that I am trying to run.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.providers.sqlite.operators.sqlite import SqliteOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1)
}

with DAG('user_processing', schedule_interval='daily', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    catchup=False) as dag:

creating_table = SqliteOperator(
    task_id='creating_table',
    sqlite_conn_id='db_sqlite',
    sql='''
        CREATE TABLE users (
            firstname TEXT NOT NULL,
            lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
            country TEXT NOT NULL,
            username TEXT NOT NULL,
            password TEXT NOT NULL,
            email TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        );
        '''
)
```

I get the following error from the Airflow UI:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/airflow/dags/user_processing.py] Traceback (most recent call 
last):
File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/airflow/providers/sqlite/operators/sqlite.py", line 21, in <module>
from airflow.providers.sqlite.hooks.sqlite import SqliteHook
File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/airflow/providers/sqlite/hooks/sqlite.py", line 21, in <module>
from airflow.hooks.dbapi import DbApiHook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.hooks.dbapi'
```

So I tried modifying the import statements as below, but still no luck.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.providers.sqlite.hooks.sqlite import SqliteHook
from airflow.providers.sqlite.operators.sqlite import SqliteOperator
```

Any ideas, or resolution to solve the issue? I am using Airflow version = **2.0.0b3** and python = **3.8.5**.
I did try to look [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/_api/airflow/hooks/index.html) and [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sqlite/stable/index.html), but not much luck.

Comment: Why are u using beta version? Use Airflow 2.1.0 which is the latest stable version.

Comment: @Elad Good shout upgraded the Airflow version and the issue was gone. I Will be providing the instructor to update his course where he mentioned using the beta version.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an old beta version of Airflow where not everything is working peoperly. you should not use beta version in production.

Use the latest Airflow stable version 2.1.0
Specificly the error that you are experiencing is resolved in that version.

Comment: Nowhere I mentioned that I am using airflow in production which I am not or plan to use the beta version in production. Thanks for writing the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Try to install airflow as following (without 'b3' beta version):
pip install apache-airflow==2.0.0 --constraint https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marclamberti/742efaef5b2d94f44666b0aec020be7c/raw/21c88601337250b6fd93f1adceb55282fb07b7ed/constraint.txt